# If statement with calculation in else statement

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, case

I am calculating the value for a column in a view using cast. I want to apply the first when statement, then the else statement but I get the error:
[Error] Execution (370: 68): ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I am trying to assign 1 as the position sequence, if there is only 1 distinct position per person. I want to apply the calculation in the else statement to calculate all others.

Here is my code below

```
CAST (
                case
                when
                 --addition when distinct position for person = 1 then 1  
                   exists (select count(distinct(position)), count(*)
                    from REPORT_DETAILS
                    where REPORT_DETAILS.PERSON_ID = src.PERSON_ID
                    group by PERSON_ID
                    having count(*) =1)     
                    
                 Then 1           
               
                Else
                  (SUBSTR (position,
                                    1,
                                    INSTR (position, '-') - 1) =
                            PRIMARY_POSITION_NUMBER
                        AND SUBSTR (position,
                                    INSTR (position, '-') + 1) =
                            PRIMARY_POSITION_NUMBER_SUFFIX
                )END
                   AS INTEGER)
               POSN_SEQUENCE,
```

Comment: Your brackets seem to be balanced. What’s the rest of your query? Also, try to simplify the query to the smallest that still has the problem (the process reducing the query is a great way to debug it and solve the problem yourself).

Comment: Instead of us trying to blindly modify a part of a query, If you provide sample data and the result you would expect from that data, it would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your **ELSE** should be a result, but you have it as a condition. the result of the first option in your case statement returns a number so your ELSE needs to return a number as well.

Running the code through a beautifier make make it a bit easier to understand. Below is a sample of what the result can be.

```sql
CAST (
           CASE
               WHEN                          --addition when distinct position for person = 1 then 1
                    EXISTS
                        (  SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT (position)), COUNT (*)
                             FROM REPORT_DETAILS
                            WHERE REPORT_DETAILS.PERSON_ID = src.PERSON_ID
                         GROUP BY PERSON_ID
                           HAVING COUNT (*) = 1)
               THEN
                   1
               WHEN (    SUBSTR (position, 1, INSTR (position, '-') - 1) = PRIMARY_POSITION_NUMBER
                     AND SUBSTR (position, INSTR (position, '-') + 1) = PRIMARY_POSITION_NUMBER_SUFFIX)
               THEN
                   2
               ELSE
                   0
           END
               AS INTEGER)    POSN_SEQUENCE
```

Another option that you can try is to use an ANALYTIC function which would be much more efficient. If you are trying to get a unique sequence broken down by PERSON_ID, you can try something like this

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
           OVER (
               PARTITION BY person_id
               ORDER BY
                   SUBSTR (position, 1, INSTR (position, '-') - 1),
                   SUBSTR (position, INSTR (position, '-') + 1))    AS posn_sequence
  FROM report_details;
```